# AngularJS put an array in $cacheFactory

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to store an array in AngularJS' $cacheFactory. When I try to get the array it's returning undefined.

Here's my code:

```
  angular.module('cacheExampleApp', []).
    controller('CacheController', ['$scope', '$cacheFactory', function($scope, $cacheFactory) {
      $scope.myArray = [
        "one",
        "two",
        "three"
      ];
      $scope.keys = [];
      $scope.cache = $cacheFactory('cacheId');
      $scope.put = function(key, value) {
        $scope.cache.put(myArray, $scope.myArray);
        $scope.keys.push(key);
      };
      console.log("myArray is:");
      console.log($scope.cache.get($scope.myArray));
    }]);
```

...and Plunker.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you ever declaring myArray, I see you putting it on $scope, but where is the myArray variable declared? your key is not declared!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you were messing with `$scope.cache.put(myArray, $scope.myArray);` this line of code in which `myArray` is undefined and code was throwing error instead of that give some key will solve your issue.

`$cacheFactory.put(key, value)` method always stored value in key value format like dictionary & then you can access those value giving its key to get method like `$cacheFactory.get(key)`

**CODE**

```
angular.module('cacheExampleApp', []).
controller('CacheController', ['$scope', '$cacheFactory',
  function($scope, $cacheFactory) {
    $scope.myArray = [
      "one",
      "two",
      "three"
    ];
    $scope.keys = [];
    $scope.cache = $cacheFactory('cacheId');
    $scope.put = function(key, value) {
      $scope.cache.put(key, value);
      $scope.keys.push(key);
    };
    $scope.put("myArray", $scope.myArray);
    $scope.put("myArray1", $scope.myArray);
    $scope.put("myArray2", $scope.myArray);
    angular.forEach($scope.keys,function(value, index){
      console.log(value + " is:");
      console.log($scope.cache.get(value));
    });

  }
]);
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SgRSvyPpvJrmxwgDlnsL?p=preview)

Hope this could help you, Thanks.